# Search a directory inside repository github

Tags: php, api, github

I trying to use `KnpLabs/php-github-api` (https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api)

I would know if it's possible to search inside a repository a specific directory

for example you have a repositori call `AddOnsMyApplication`, inside you have a directory callled analytics, another called products

```
  AddOnsMyApplication
    --- analytics
    ---- products
```

To have information about AddOnsMyApplication, it's ok

```
$client->api('repo')->find('AddOnsMyApplication');
```

but to search information by a keywords inside AddOnsMyApplication, 
I don't know how to make that.

For example inside AddOnsMyApplication I research `"%an%"` to have all the addons with An like analytics

Thank you